# Using HTML5 Mobile boilerplate (MBP) for developing mobile sites

Tags: html, css, mobile, xhtml, web-standards

I want to create a mobile site and want to target almost all devices from High end (Iphone,android) to low end (nokia's, LG Flip-phones).

Which method to choose for dvelopment:

1. Developing 2 sites one built on HTML5 for targeting latest handsets and second built on XHTML MP for supporting old handsets also.
2. Using Mobile boilerplate - developing site on HTML5 and including fallback script (with the help of modernizr) for handsets which does not support certain HTML5 features.

Which method seems convenient and sensible.

Answer (score 1):

When you say **mobile** what kind of *output* do you want at the mobile devices?

like a **mobile app** or a **website**?

if it's ok to be like a **mobile app**, I would suggest [**jQuery Mobile**](http://jquerymobile.com/) (if you're used to jQuery), [**Sencha Touch**](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch), if you love javascript developing or any other mobile framework.

They will support almost any mobile device out there, that at least runs Opera Mobile.

Take a look, for example, at [jQuery Mobile Platforms](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) that will run.

If it's a normal **website feel** that you want, I would suggest [**Bootstrap Framework**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) with their [**responsive** approach](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples).

Comment: its a website....and at first I was thinking to use jquerymobile only....but then I read many questions on stackoverflow which says that HTML5 wont be good if you want to support old handsets....so got confused

Comment: you should go with **jQueryMobile** then, it supports a lot and several problems are already fixed, as, if you're doing something from scratch you will end up wasting time debugging just cause an element does not show correct in Opera Mobile for Nokia N7, but works fine on Opera running on an Android device ... 

I stated using jQuery Mobile when it was beta (0.6 if I recall correctly) and there's so much fixed since that I won't think anything else apart of **Sencha Touch** (but here, it's a paid framework and you need to know ExtJs).